# Definite Integral - help with choosing which solution is the right one?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2-4x)^3}}dx $

So my friend and I did the same question but ended up with different answers.

**(1) We did the same steps here:** 
$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{((x-2)^2-4)^3}}dx $ 
 
Let $(x-2)^2 = 4sec^2(u) $ 
$ x-2 = 2 sec(u) $ 
$ x = 2sec(u) + 2 $ 
$ dx = 2sec(u)tan(u)du $ 
 
$ =2 \int \frac{sec(u)tan(u)}{\sqrt{(4sec^2(u)-4)^3}}du $ 
$ =\int \frac{sec(u)tan(u)}{\sqrt{(sec^2(u)-1)^3}}du $ 
$ =\int \frac{sec(u)tan(u)}{\sqrt{(tan^2(u))^3}}du $ 
$ =\int \frac{sec(u)tan(u)}{tan^3(u)}du $ 
$ =\int \frac{sec(u)}{tan^2(u)}du $ 
 
**Continued (1) with my solution:** 
$ =\int \frac{sec(u)}{sec^2(u)-1}du $ 
$ =\int \frac{sec(u)}{sec^2(u)}du - \int \frac{sec(u)}{1}du $ 
$ =\int \frac{1}{sec(u)}du - ln|sec(u)+tan(u)|+C $ 
$ =sin(u) - ln|sec(u)+tan(u)|+C $ 
 
$ u= sec^{-1}(\frac{x-2}{2}) $ Which will give a right angle triangle with hypotenuse = $ x-2 $ and adjacent side = $ 2 $ and the opposite side = $ \sqrt{(x-2)^2-4} $ 
 
Final answer: $ \frac{\sqrt{(x-2)^2-4}}{x-2} - ln| \frac{x-2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{(x-2)^2-4}}{2} |+C $ 
 
**Continued (1) with friend's solution:** 
$ =\int \frac{1}{cos(u)} \cdot \frac{cos^2(u)}{sin^2(u)}du $ 
$ =\int \frac{cos(u)}{sin^2(u)}du $ 
 
Let $ w = sin(u) $ 
$ dw = cos(u)du $ 
 
$ =\int \frac{1}{w^2}du $ 
$ =\frac{-1}{w} + C $ 
$ =\frac{-1}{sinu} + C $ 
 
$ u= sec^{-1}(\frac{x-2}{2}) $ Which will give a right angle triangle with hypotenuse = $ x-2 $ and adjacent side = $ 2 $ and the opposite side = $ \sqrt{(x-2)^2-4} $ 
 
Final answer: $ \frac{2-x}{\sqrt{(x-2)^2-4}} $

Comment: Take a look at your solution:$$=\int \frac{sec(u)}{sec^2(u)-1}du\\=\int \frac{sec(u)}{sec^2(u)}du - \int \frac{sec(u)}{1}du$$

Comment: Arrrrrrg that was super silly of me. Thank you for noticing that mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your friends solution:

$$
\int \frac{cos(u)}{sin^2(u)}du = \int\frac{1}{sin(u)}\frac{cos(u)}{sin(u)}du = \int csc(u)cot(u) \; du = -csc(u) + C
$$

Now put this answer back in terms of x from your original substitution.